# Not able to charge my Horizontal Pod Autoscaling on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to test my HPA by sending requests to my php pod.

Here is my Deployment configuration :

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: staging
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-sso
  namespace: staging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: php-sso
  # remove replica if using gitops
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: php-sso
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: php-sso
          image: myImage
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 256Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 256Mi
```

And my service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-sso
  namespace: staging
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: php-sso
```

The pods runs well (no error), but when I'm trying this command:

```
kubectl run -i --tty -n staging load-generator --pod-running-timeout=5m0s --rm --image=busybox:1.28 --restart=Never -- /bin/sh -c "while sleep 0.01; do wget -q -O- http://php-sso; done"
```

I have this error :

```
warning: couldn't attach to pod/load-generator, falling back to streaming logs: error dialing backend: remote error: tls: internal error
pod "load-generator" deleted
Error from server: Get "https://10.0.31.14:10250/containerLogs/staging/load-generator/load-generator": remote error: tls: internal error
```

Here are my pods :

```
kube-system   coredns-5b9fdd8ff8-9hkpv          1/1     Running   0          129m
kube-system   coredns-5b9fdd8ff8-dvkcj          1/1     Running   0          129m
kube-system   metrics-server-7cf9657999-9hzt9   1/1     Running   0          124m
staging       load-generator                    0/1     Pending   0          34s
staging       php-sso-67547878fd-xlgt8          1/1     Running   0          27m
```

And services:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default       kubernetes       ClusterIP   172.20.0.1      <none>        443/TCP         17h
kube-system   kube-dns         ClusterIP   172.20.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   17h
kube-system   metrics-server   ClusterIP   172.20.47.210   <none>        443/TCP         125m
staging       php-sso          ClusterIP   172.20.223.20   <none>        80/TCP          122m
```

Does anyone have an idea?

All this runs on AWS EKS with a terraform strategy

Comment: `kubectl get csr`. Do you see any `Pending` certificates when you run this command?